# DiscordJs send a message to a specific text channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel knowing the name.

I've tried this method, but it doesn't work:

```
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(c => c.name === 'the channel name')
```

`cache` doesn't seem to exist, but removing it doesn't return the channel either.

I also tried doing this and it works, but I would like to send the message knowing the name and not the id.

```
const che = client.channels.get("ID");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `client.channels.get("ID")` works, it means you are using `discord.js v11`. v11 does not use Managers, and thus has no need for a `cache` property.

Then, you can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
client.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'example-name')
// or
client.channels.find('name', 'example-name')
```